# charset problem (Excel)

Tags: excel, jsp, character-encoding

Non-English Values are looking like upside with their charsets.

```
 "application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=cp1256";
```

Values on Excel is : ÊÖÇÑÈ ÊæŞÚÇÊ ÔåÑ ÃßÊæÈÑ İí ÓæŞ ÇáÜPP

```
 "application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=cp1254";
```

Values on Excel is : ????? ???? ??????? ???? ????????????

```
"application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8";
```

Values on Excel is : ÊÖÇÑÈ ÊæŞÚÇÊ ÔåÑ ÃßÊæÈÑ İí ÓæŞ ÇáÜPP

What is the correct charset?

Comment: I changed the application part as;
'"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=cp1256";'

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit cryptic, leaving a lot to be guessed (like: what the JSP tag is doing there?).

So I will make a wild guess. Since Windows uses UTF-16 for Unicode encoding, try this in the charset.

Comment: UTF-16 value= *6'1( *HB9'* 4G1   so this doesnt work too. I've a java class that setting charset. from data programme gets non-english characters and shows it on JSP page. when I convert it to excel with: 'return "application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=cp1254"' the problem begins

Comment: @xx yy: you should edit your question and add more information: what is the data, where it comes from, how it is generated/gotten from. And how you output Excel data from a JSP page. With better understanding of the code flow, we can make better answers.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 or UTF-16 will both work as they are global.

- cp1254 is Turkish and does not support all European letters.
- cp1256 is west european so it will work, but be warned that it
  doesn't support non-European letters, so it can't handle, say,
  Arabic.

In your case, UTF is the 'best' answer.

Comment: I tried UTF-8,but it showed weird characters as cp1256. I quess there is another way to solve this problem without charset. but how dont know.